# Open source url shortener with memcached integration?

Tags: memcached, url-shortener

Is there an open source url shortener solution that features a cache level (via memcached) on top of a db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://briancray.com/posts/free-php-url-shortener-script/)

It does not have memcache integration but it does use a local store. With a bit of work you can change it to work with a memcache adapter.